# Why relative src becomes absolute, Apache, HTML5?

Tags: apache, src

Why relative src becomes absolute, Apache, HTML5?

project structure:

```
host/public/somedomain.com
host/public/somedomain.com/public
host/public/somedomain.com/public/index.php
//notvisible from outside
host/private/somedomainPrivate/core/App.php
host/private/somedomainPrivate/js 
host/private/somedomainPrivate/js/loadprivate.js
```

in host/public/somedomain.com/public/index.php

```
//i create App.php
use core/App
$app = new App(); 
//$app contains some logics, to load other files and generate views.
```

in host/private/somedomainPrivate/core/App.php

```
// i would like to refer to loadprivate.js using
define( 'INC_ROOT', dirname(__DIR__) ); 
echo "<br><br> in App.php INC_ROOT =". INC_ROOT ; // host/private/somedomainPrivate
define('URL_VIEWFNC_JS', INC_ROOT . '/js' ); 
echo '<script src="'. URL_VIEWFNC_JS .'/loadprivate.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>';
```

I am getting GET error, that file could not be loaded: 
https://somedomain.com/js/loadprivate.js

i mean the relative url pointing to `host/private/somedomainPrivate/js/loadprivate.js`  is tranformed to absolute  `https://somedomain.com/js/loadprivate.js`.

Is it possible to load `loadprivate.js` from private folder?

Comment: You need to learn to differentiate between URLs, and local file system paths.

Comment: working solution is to move loadprivate.js to  host/public/somedomain.com/public/js/

Comment: but i would like to load from private folder, not accessible from web ( my hosting company says that file out of  `host/public/` are not accessible . Maybe it is not possible for `src` attribute? Most probably

Comment: another working solution is to rewrite javascript as a string, and echo from php file. `include_once(loadprivate.js.php)` works perfectly from `host/private` because it does not need `src` .

Comment: _"but i would like to load from private folder, not accessible from web"_ - and where exactly do you want this to _work_? Can't be on the web then.

Comment: my host says that only host/public is accessible from the web.  I moved all my project to host/private but when i try to load scripts, src does not point correctly . I use relative path as given in question, but it is appended to the public path .  I mean i use `host/private/somedomainPrivate/js/loadprivate.js' hoping to load file from this folder, but it becomes appended to url  `https://somedomain.com/js/loadprivate.js` , which does not exists

Comment: You want my browser to download your JS file. This happens "on the web". Making it not accessible "from the web" is therefor nonsense.

Comment: exactly what i wanted to ask, if it is possible? Thanks for the answer. But i would like to add that it is possible if you rewrite to php string, and then echo. You can include any php file from private part of server, and echo from it any content.  Seems it does not work only with files loaded through src attribute.

Comment: _"But i would like to add that it is possible if you rewrite to php string, and then echo"_ - then I would still get the _content_ of your script file, just not from path A, but from path B. How would that make _any_ difference to the outcome?